環境構築の設定 Node.js、yarnインストールしてasdfで設定するには
現在Ruby on Rails で宿泊検索 LINE Botを作るため、環境構築でRubyをインストールした段階です。
学習に沿って進めていると、Node.js、yarnをインストールするにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？
行ったこと
install
nodebrew install v8.9.4
rails-hotel-search-linebot katouyuuka$ nodebrew install-binary latest
Fetching: https://nodejs.org/dist/v22.1.0/node-v22.1.0-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
Warning: Failed to open the file 
Warning: /Users/katouyuuka/.nodebrew/src/v22.1.0/node-v22.1.0-darwin-arm64.tar.
Warning: gz: No such file or directory

